# Attempting to set variable based on conditional statement in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-statements

So today is literally my first day of learning a programming language so I'm very new to Python. I'm taking the online Python for Informatics course at the University of Michigan and our first real assignment is to create a simple gross pay rate calculator.

That was simple enough so I decided I wanted to expand what the program could do to calculate net pay and account for taxes. The trouble I'm having is determining how I can dynamically (if that's even the right word) set the value of the variable **"taxrate"** based on a series of conditional statements.

I have yet to find the answer in searching through Python's site and Stack Overflow. I think my limited understanding of programming probably is limiting my ability to interpret properly what I have found.

Just looking for a little help:

Code:

```
#This program is intended to calculate the net pay of employees
#This first section includes a loop for mistakes and finds gross pay

while True:

hours = raw_input('How many hours do you work weekly?')
hours1 = float(hours)
rate = raw_input('What is your hourly rate of pay?')
rate1 = float(rate)
grosspay = hours1 * rate1
taxstatus = raw_input('Do you pay taxes?')


#This secdtion is establishing the tax bracket the user falls into
taxbracket = taxrate
if grosspay <= 1000:
    taxrate = 0.90
if grosspay > range(1000,1500):
    taxrate = 0.78
if grosspay >= 1501:
    taxrate = 0.63

# This section is intended to calculate pay after taxes
grosspay = hours1 * rate1
if taxstatus == 'yes':
    netpay = grosspay * taxrate
print'Your weekly pay after taxes is',netpay
if not taxstatus:
    print grosspay
```

When I run this in PyCharm it lets me know that **"taxrate"** hasn't been defined. I ultimately want the program to set the **"taxrate"** based on what the users **"grosspay"** is. Is what I'm trying to do possible? I'm assuming it is and that I just don't understand how to do it.

**Any help is greatly appreciated** and in case someone is wondering what the loop is for I've got a user error checker that I'm working on after this portion of the program completes.

Comment: Indentation is very important in python

Comment: `taxbracket = taxrate` get rid of this line, since you're not using `taxbracket` anywhere

Comment: First, the line `taxbracket = taxrate` is where your problem is, since you haven't yet defined `taxrate`. But you never use `taxbracket` either, so you can delete that line entirely. Second, you'll need to change `if grosspay > range(1000,1500):` to `if grosspay <= 1500:`

Comment: Pynchia In PyCharm everything is indented appropriately. I wasn't certain syntactically perfect indentation was necessary for understanding my question. Still a good note for a beginner :)

NightShadeQueen Thanks.

@DavidRobinson Thanks. Will that conflict with the previous statement of if grosspay <= 1000: taxrate = 0.90 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is a bit suspect in `if grosspay > range(1000, 1500)`. What would it mean to be "greater" than a range of numbers? my guess is that the `grosspay` you input is, in fact, within the range `[1000, 1500)`, so it hits this logic bug in your code and fails to assign it to anything.

The usual way to check if a number is within a range is to use the `in` operator.

```
if some_num in range(1, 10):
    print("some_num is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9")
```

However you'll notice that `some_num` *MUST* be contained in the integer range `[1, 9]` for this to trigger. If `some_num` is `7.5`, this will fail. This is *incredibly* likely in the case of gross pay. What are the chances of someone's pay coming out to an exactly even dollar amount?

Instead what you could do is:

```
if grosspay <= 1000:
    taxrate = 0.90
elif 1000 < grosspay <= 1500:
    taxrate = 0.78
elif 1500 < grosspay:
    taxrage = 0.63
```

using `elif` instead of a series of `if`s makes the code slightly more efficient, since `if/elif/else` is by definition one block that is mutually exclusive. In other words:

```
a = 1
b = 2

if a == 1:
    print("This gets done!")
if b == 2:
    print("This gets done!")

if a == 1:
    print("This gets done!")
elif b == 2:
    print("BUT THIS DOESN'T!")
else:
    print("(this doesn't either...)")
```

Comment: I honestly wasn't certain how to create a series of numbers that I wanted my comparison to consider. Given where I am in the class I hadn't  been familiarized with elif but that's very helpful. That worked like a Charm! Thank you very much!